# UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout with section header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I hope you are already aware of a control called 'UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout'. Is there a way to implement 'section headers' in this?

Thanks,

Reno Jones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation says that:](https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout#limitation)

> No supplementary view and decoration view.

Fork it and try to rewrite code.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked at it, my bad.